# Change Of Sign In Functions

Tags: calculus

If a function changes it's sign then is it necessary that it will change its sign while passing through some point? if yes then what about wildy oscillating functions like $$\begin{align} f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if 'x' is rational} \\ -1 &  \text{if 'x' is irrational} \end{cases} \end{align}$$, passing through which point does $f(x)$ change it's sign?
$$$$Plz Help

Answer (score 1):

With all continuous functions, then if the function changes sign at different points, there's a point in between when the function is $0$, i.e., it changes sign there, due to theorem's like the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) (and, in particular, the listed corollary of Bolzano's theorem stating that there's a root in the interval).

However, this is not always necessarily true with discontinuous functions, like your $f(x)$ where it's only values are either $1$ or $-1$ and, thus, there's no point where $f(x)$ will "change its sign", i.e., where it's $0$.